# How can i get the spring() animation right

Tags: swiftui

On button click i want my MapScreen to "slide" in from the bottom. So i used .annimation(spring()). This used to work, now i get the animation deprecation (needs an value). How can i solve this on the spring() animation.

Is it possible to set a WithAnimation on the if showMapScreen toggle ?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @State private var showMapScreen = false

    
    var body: some View {

        
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        
            VStack {
                Button("Show Map") {
                        
                        showMapScreen.toggle()
                    
            
                   
                       }
                }
        

                if showMapScreen {
                    
                    MapScreen()
                        .padding(.top, 400)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .animation(spring(), value:???)
       
                  
                }

        }
    }
}
```

//second view

```
  struct MapScreen: View {
    
        @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: 
         CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.12), span: 
         MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
    

    
    var body: some View{
                
        ZStack(alignment:.top) {
         
            Color.white
     
                    //handle for dragging
                    Capsule()
                        .frame(width:40, height:10)
                        .zIndex(2.0)
                        
                    Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion)
    
                
        }  
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
          

    }
   

}
```

Comment: *Is it possible to set a WithAnimation on the if showMapScreen toggle* Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it into container and put animation to container allowing to animate its content, like

```
VStack {
    if showMapScreen {
        MapScreen()
            .padding(.top, 400)
            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    }
}
.animation(spring(), value: showMapScreen)   // << here !!
```

Comment: Ok, but before i could  do the animation directly on the Mapscreen().animation(.spring()). Is that right

Comment: And yes, and no, that modifier worked globally so could affect any changes applied by previous (or internal) modifiers which resulted in many bugs, that's why Apple deprecated it. The animation(.., value:) existed and before and provided above is correct way to use it, of course you can attach it to any parent container, but it is better to limit animatable part exactly to what is only needed.

Comment: @saro you could do the animation directly- Mapscreen().animation(.spring(), value: showMapScreen). The only difference is passing the value to track changes that trigger the animation.

Answer (score 0):

To use the method *animation(_:value:)*, you must pass the parameter 'value'. 
With it, we specify the property, the change of which will trigger the animation.

```
MapScreen()
           .padding(.top, 400)
           .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
           .animation(spring(), value: showMapScreen)
```

From [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/animation(_:value:)):

> **value** 
> A value to monitor for changes.